# Getting data from e-mail to c#

Tags: c#, email

I wonder it is possible to get data from email message to c#?
It is?

Answer (score 0):

If you have got an account configured in Outlook you may consider automating it. See [How to automate Outlook from another program](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/kb/201096?wa=wsignin1.0) for more information. And [C# app automates Outlook (CSAutomateOutlook)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSAutomateOutlook-a3b7bdc9) for sample code.

Also you may consider developing a managed add-in for Outlook. In that case you will be able to handle Outlook events and track what users do. See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First Application-Level Add-in for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.